# Rare elements in arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting, divide-and-conquer

We are given a sorted array A[1..n] of n integers. We say an element x E A is rare if it occurs
in A strictly less than n/10 times. That is, x is rare if there is some index 1 <= i <= n such that
A(i) = x, and there are strictly less than n/10 distinct indices j for which A(j) = x. Our goal
is to find a rare element, or output that A contains no rare elements.

**Input**: A sorted array A[1..n] of n integers.

**Output**: A rare element x E A, or the output “No rare element exists in A.”

**Is there an O(log n) time algorithm for the rare element problem? What is it?**

T(n) = 10 T(n/10) + O(1) gives O(n) time which is not good enough for me.

Comment: Sounds like homework, and whats the question?

Comment: Updated with question. Doing this work at home. So, yeah its a homework.   Not an assignment, if you mean that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to do it in `O(log n)`. I assume, that you already have this array in memory. Otherwise it's impossible to do it faster than in `O(n)`, because you need to read array at least.

Let's say that `step` is the biggest integer that is less than `n/10`. If `step` is equal to zero then we don't have rare elements obviously.

Consider the following algorithm:

```
int start = 1;
while (true) {
  if (n - start + 1 <= step) {
    OutputRare(A[start]); Exit;
  }
  int next_index = start + step;
  if (A[start] != A[next_index]) {
    OutputRare(A[start); Exit;
  }
  // Here we need to find the smallest index starting from start with
  // element that is not equal to A[start]. If such element does not
  // exist function returns -1.
  next_index = FindFirstNonEqual(A[start], start);
  if (next_index == -1) {
    // There is no rare elements
    Exit;
  }
  start = next_index;
}
```

This algorithm either returns rare element, or increases start by at least `step`. Which means that it will increase start ~10 times (because every step is about `n/10`). `FindFirstNonEqual` can be implemented using binary search, which means that total complexity is `O(10log n) = O(log n)`.